# Challenge in creating multiple PDF files in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am facing some challenge to create multiple PDF files in informatica 10.2.0, Please find the details below:

**Requirement** : - We need to spilt single xml file into multiple PDF files based on condition.

**Tools used** : - Informatica Powercenter, Informatica Developer.

**Challenge**  : - I have created data processor in informatica developer and used this as service in informatica powercenter and created single PDF file
                         But not able to create multiple PDF files with this service. I have used sorter to sort the file based on my condition to split the file and then used transaction control to commit records based on the condition used and passing these records to the UDT transformation (calling service in this transformation) and then passing the output Buffer port to target.
Here in UDT transformation I have given Input type and Output type as 'file' in UDT settings tab in mapping.

Could anyone please provide suggestion to achieve a solution for this technical challenge.

Comment: Transaction control is for timing your commits, why aren't you using a router to split the pipeline and direct the records to separate targets?

Comment: Alternative is to sort by your file split criteria earlier in the pipeline then the transaction control file splitting would make some sense

Comment: We are doing the same way which you mentioned, i.e, we are sorting file based on the split criteria and then using transaction control to split the file. It is creating multiple PDF files but data is not getting split, instead all records are loading to all the PDF files which is created.

Comment: @DanielMachet Please be informed that I have updated my question so that I guess now you will be able to understand my issue in detail. Please let me know if you require further details. Also for your information it is not necessary for me to use XML file only as source I can go for text file as well, I have tried with text file as source also. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I'm scratching my head I'm afraid, one unknown for me is udt which I've not used before - have you tried routing the records to a flat file as a test to see if the same behaviour occurs? Also (and I'm clutching at straws here) are you using a filename port for the output files?

Comment: You are saying to check by using router transformation instead of transaction control, but we have millions of records in source file based on member id so that is the reason we used transaction control to commit on records based on the member id. If our condition is defined or lets say we have only (if else statements) then we can go for router transformation. But in this case condition is not defined, if i have millions of member ids i need to generate millions of PDF files.

Comment: Umm actually I was asking what happens when you go to a flat file instead of udt but I see you've answered that below.

Answer (score 0):

create a variable to identify when a change or new xml is processed and use this to issue commit/continue in the Transaction control.

Comment: Actually without UDT transformation when i connect from transaction control to flat file target it is working, i am getting separate files based on my condition. Only problem is when i connect from transaction control to UDT transformation, I am not getting the result as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think the transaction control is probably the wrong route to use here - try this https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/1/154788.aspx

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for sharing the link, i tried the same way how it is mentioned in the given link. i have some concern here, in the link it is mentioned as output =Outputfile i guess it will not work in powercenter. We have to give output=Resultfile() to work in powercenter that is what i got the information when initially i started working on developer, anyway let me check this in informatica powercenter and will update on it. I actually was looking for this link, very useful i feel.Great :)